# Outlook 2019 registry profile location

Tags: outlook

Such an easy answer for that question? Never mind! Please read carefully before answering that by Google.

Today I faced an Office 365 installed in such weird way, that was installed in this location: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Outlook_16051.11601.20204.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16

I have an application that changes default signature for each account that is working from office 2000 to 2019 (on PCs excluding this one).

I'm able to change anything in the registry profile location (HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles) but it is having no effect in the installed Outlook.

I'm also unable to find currently active settings anywhere in the registry. **What I'm missing?**

I also post it on MS TechNet:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c6742cee-4891-4a54-a5c7-81e01cc44354/outlook-2019-profile-location?forum=Office2016ITPro

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use Windows Store version of Microsoft Office.
The registry keys for those WindowsApps are saved in a file seperated from the normal registry.
To access this part of the registry you have to get the location of the file.

1. First open Outlook, then the registry file is mounted.
2. Check this registry key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist
3. You should see something like:
   \REGISTRY\WC\Silo12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234user_sid
   \Device\HarddiskVolume2\ProgramData\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\S-1-5-21-1112233456-123456789-123456786-1234\SystemAppData\Helium\User.dat
4. You will need this part:
   ProgramData\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\S-1-5-21-1112233456-123456789-123456786-1234\SystemAppData\Helium\User.dat
5. After this, close Outlook and open the registry editor.
   Load this hive (if Windows is on C)
   C:\ProgramData\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\S-1-5-21-1112233456-123456789-123456786-1234\SystemAppData\Helium\User.dat

Then you will see all the user settings of Office.

I found this file/key using ProcMon from Microsoft.

Comment: do you know how to list this key using the command line or programicly?

Comment: You could use "reg query" and the "reg load" command in the command line.